Preparing data for Multistate Markov Model
I have a dataset of 5 columns. The first column is participant identifier, and the other 4 are longitudinal timepoints (waves). At each timepoint, each participant is classified into a "frailty state" (robust, prefrail, frail, dead)
I want to use multistate markov model in R to calculate the transition probabilites between frailty states from wave x to wave x+1.
This is the code I ran:
msm_model <- msm(data = df_filtered, 
                 subject = "ID", 
                 from = c("W1", "W2", "W3"), 
                 to = c("W2", "W3", "W4"),
                 qmatrix = q_matrix,
                 formula = "Robust" ~ W1 + W2 + W3 + W4 + 
                           "Pre-Frail" ~ W1 + W2 + W3 + W4 + 
                           "Frail" ~ W1 + W2 + W3 + W4 +
                   "Dead" ~ W2 + W3 + W4)

and got this error message:
Error in model.frame.default(data = list(ID = c("1001", "1002",  :
variable lengths differ (found for '(state)')
can anyone offer some advice?
